# Can amino acids exist in the completely non charged state?

Tags: amino-acids

Typically amino acids can exist in three states, as far as I’m aware, which depend on the pH:
[image: Three States:]
However, most of the time I see amino acids in a completely uncharged state when shown in textbooks or on the internet:
[image]

The issue is, I cannot seem to think of any possible pH where such a state can exist. Please correct me if I’m wrong on this and tell me under what conditions such a state can occur. However, if I’m right then why do they show it as such… for simplicity?

Comment: That may occur uncharged in pure form or dissolved in polar aprotic solvents, not in water, where such form exist in trace equilibrium concentrations.

Comment: If I had a button to turn comments into answers…

Comment: @Karsten Kinda did that for you ;) Duping is close enough for me.